# Enable-PSRemoting Error

Tags: powershell, remote

I manage a network of over 100 2008R2 Servers.  There is no domain on the network for various reasons.  I am running `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` on all the servers.  Some of them are running just fine, but a bunch are producing an error creating a temp file.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Enable-PSRemoting -Force
WinRM already is set up to receive requests on this machine.
WinRM already is set up for remote management on this machine.
Register-PSSessionConfiguration : Cannot write shell configuration data into temporary file C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\tldeudyv.td3psshell.xml. Try again. Reason for failure: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\tldeudyv.td3psshell.xml'..
At line:57 char:60
+                     $null = Register-PSSessionConfiguration <<<<  Microsoft.PowerShell32 -processorarchitecture x86 -
force
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Register-PSSessionConfiguration], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RegisterPSSessionConfigurationCommand

PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

In addition to the error above, it also produces an error in the error log with ID 10149.

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WinRM
Date:          3/6/2017 9:14:31 AM
Event ID:      10149
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      CCAC1-16
Description:
The WinRM service is not listening for WS-Management requests. 

 User Action 
 If you did not intentionally stop the service, use the following command to see the WinRM configuration: 

 winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WinRM" Guid="{A7975C8F-AC13-49F1-87DA-5A984A4AB417}" EventSourceName="WinRM" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="7">10149</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-03-06T14:14:31.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>45009</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>CCAC1-16</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData Name="Stopped Listening">
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Are you using a specific Windows Management Framework version?

Comment: 2.0 as it installed originally.  No difference there between the servers that are working and the servers that aren't.